# Windows scheduler keeps asking if I want to keep using Python.exe to open .py files

Tags: python, permissions, windows-8.1, windows-task-scheduler

I have a script that scheduler is to run daily. Each time, it asks if I want to keep using Python.exe, even though it's already the default program for opening such files.

Some advice elsewhere suggested deleting the `UserChoice` registry entry for .py files, which did nothing to resolve.

How can I get my system to stop prompting, so it will run the script without user input?

Comment: Default programs are configured on a per-user basis.  I'd hazard a guess that the scheduler is looking in the settings for the local system account, or for the account the script is configured to run in, rather than your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the scheduler pointed directly at the .py file? If so, I'd recommend instead to tell the scheduler to run python.exe and pass the .py file as an argument.

For example, if the script you want to run is C:\Files\script.py put this into the scheduler:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe "C:\Files\script.py"
```